# setting field value from a drop down on a form using setFieldValue

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to set the shipping address to new on the sales order form and is confused if I can use setFieldValue to select from the drop down before I set the new address field values

```
var salesOrder = nlapiCreateRecord('salesorder');
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('entity', customerInternalID);
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('location', LOCATION);
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('custbody_ebay_order_id', ebayOrderID);
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('currency', 1);
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('custbody_execute_script', 'T');

        var utc_trandate = nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']/CreatedTime');
        var trandate = dateToNetsuiteFormat(utc_trandate);
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('trandate', trandate);
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('shippingcost', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingServiceCost'));
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'address', defaultAddress);
        salesOrder.setFieldValue('billaddresslist', defaultAddress);
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipaddresslist', 'New');
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipcountry', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Country'));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipisresidential', 'T');
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipattention', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Name'));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipaddressee', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Name'));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipaddrphone', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Phone').substring(0, 12));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipaddr1', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Street1'));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipaddr2', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Street2'));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipcity', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/CityName'));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipstate', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/StateOrProvince'));
        salesorder.setFieldValue('shipzip', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/PostalCode'));
```

Comment: Might be worth to show what the function looks like for ` salesorder.setFieldValue`

Comment: I've edited it in the post

Answer (score 0):

Addresses are sub-records on sales order, to set them you need to fetch sub-record first and then set values in it. Also you don't need to explicitly save the sub-record it gets saved with the parent sales order itself.
Example in SuiteScript2.0

```
// first fetch address sub-record
addressRecord = salesOrderRecord.getSubrecord({ fieldId: 'shippingaddress' });
// then set data on sub-record
addressRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'shipattention', value: 'ABC' });
// set other required fields
```